# How to change IP address of multiple computers using batch file script?

Tags: windows, script, batch-file, active-directory, group-policy

How to change IP address of multiple computers using batch file script. I'm planning to run this via GPO so that i can change numbers of computers using 1 script. Hope you can help me.

Comment: I doubt this is possible, but I'd be interesting in seeing if it is.

Comment: yah, currently i have batch file working but only on single computer. I incorporated it via GPO so that i can run it to specific computer remotely. Now i'm working to implement it to multiple computers using single script, but i'm not good in making script that's why i'm lloking for help :) but thank you checking my queries.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be on Computer A, Run a batch script on Computer A. And it's going to change the local IP address of Computer B through Z?

Comment: No not like that. what i'm planning is to create a batch file that can change IP address of any computers inside my Active Directory. If it is possible i want to run that script using GPO so that i can execute the command remotely to all computers inside my network. I'm thinking if it someone has an idea creating that kind of script that can identify the machine using unique mac address and each Mac Address i will provide unique IP Address and that the script will do incase it is possible. Hope i explained well, sorry if not. :)

Comment: How about using DHCP?